# how to show data in row on Stacked bar chat by using MS Charts Control

Tags: mschart

I need to show the data from a SQL query as shown below on stacked bar chart by using MS Chart control on ASPX page

[image]

Where I have to show the chart like this

```
    </asp:Chart>
```

[image]

Comment: Any joy with my suggested solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should show some code if you want help, but here's a simple `vb.net` solution.

I added a chart to the page and then ran the following code to produce the below chart

[image]

*Create your datatable - you can drop this and connect with SQL*

```
    Dim t As New DataTable
    t.Columns.Add("Risk Categories")
    t.Columns.Add("High Impact Risks")
    t.Columns.Add("Medium Impact Risks")
    t.Columns.Add("Low Impact Risks")
    t.Columns.Add("No Impact Risks")

    t.Rows.Add("Compliance,Law,Legislation", "4", "1", "0", "5")
    t.Rows.Add("Construction", "5", "1", "1", "0")
    t.Rows.Add("Design", "3", "1", "0", "0")
    t.Rows.Add("Financial", "6", "0", "0", "2")
    t.Rows.Add("Human Resources", "2", "0", "0", "10")
    t.Rows.Add("Information & Communication", "1", "0", "0", "1")
    t.Rows.Add("Interface", "1", "0", "0", "0")
    t.Rows.Add("Logistic", "0", "1", "0", "6")
    t.Rows.Add("Management", "0", "1", "0", "0")
    t.Rows.Add("Planning", "3", "0", "0", "1")
```

*Add the points to the new chart*

```
   Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
    With Chart1.Series(0)
        .Name = "High Impact Risks"
        .Points.DataBind(t.DefaultView, "Risk Categories", "High Impact Risks", Nothing)
    End With

    Chart1.Series.Add("Medium Impact Risks")
    Chart1.Series(1).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
    With Chart1.Series(1)
        .Name = "Medium Impact Risks"
        .Points.DataBind(t.DefaultView, "Risk Categories", "Medium Impact Risks", Nothing)
    End With

    Chart1.Series.Add("Low Impact Risks")
    Chart1.Series(2).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
    With Chart1.Series(2)
        .Points.DataBind(t.DefaultView, "Risk Categories", "Low Impact Risks", Nothing)
    End With

    Chart1.Series.Add("No Impact Risks")
    Chart1.Series(3).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedBar
    With Chart1.Series(3)
        .Points.DataBind(t.DefaultView, "Risk Categories", "No Impact Risks", Nothing)
    End With

    ''Show All Categories on RHS axis
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont

    ''Move legend to bottom and center
    Chart1.Legends(0).Docking = Docking.Bottom
    Chart1.Legends(0).Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
```

Comment: Thank you dear for your reply, leme implement this.

Comment: Hi dear, if  we have more than 16 rows instead of 4 as shown below, but charts is still showing 3 or 4 categories on Y why its not showing

Comment: Hi dear, if  we have more than 16 rows instead of 4 as shown below, but charts is still showing 3 or 4 categories why its not showing more than 3/4 row data         //t.Rows.Add("Human Resources", "2", "0", "0", "10");
                //t.Rows.Add("Information & Communication", "1", "0", "0", "1");
                //t.Rows.Add("Interface", "1", "0", "0", "0");
                //t.Rows.Add("Logistic", "0", "1", "0", "6");

                //t.Rows.Add("Management", "0", "1", "0", "0");
                //t.Rows.Add("Planning", "3", "0", "0", "1");

Comment: `Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1               Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont` Will rearrange the axis for you. Hopefully this answers the question now?

Comment: Yes that why I want to do. on my side I am not able to show right side  risk impact on my chart. whole chart is occupied by chart

Comment: would you like to share your aspx file lines, my aspx looks like this <asp:Chart ID="chRisks" runat="server" Width="700px" Height="500px"  >
       <series>
      <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="StackedBar" BorderColor="180, 26, 59, 105" Color="220, 224, 64, 10" ></asp:Series>
      </series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" >
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking but `Chart1.Legends(0).Docking = Docking.Bottom` will move legend to bottom and create more space. If you have more questions I suggest you open a new question